# JavaScript Loop to setData method

Tags: javascript, django, loops, web, highcharts

I want to dynamically update the data for every series I have in a line chart (Highcharts.js). Currently, I'm doing it by manually passing new data to a series using the setData method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(chart_id).highcharts({
chart: chart,
title: title,
credits: credits,
xAxis: {},
Axis: yAxis,
legend: legend,
series: series

 });

   var chartz = $(chart_id).highcharts();
   $('#data-labels').click(function () {
    chartz.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,25,29],true,true,true);

    });
```

What I would like to do is update:

```
chartz.series[i]
```

Where is the index of each individual series (I have about 36 and new ones are added all the time)

How do I code and implement a javascript for loop that counts the series length and passes into the series[i].setData variable? I'm very inexperienced in JavaScript, so I'm not really sure where to even begin or where to place this function? I'm guessing it will look something like (where i < is pseudo code):

```
for (var i = 0; i < "series length + 1"; i++)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chartz.series.length; i++) {
    chartz.series[i].setData(DATA);
});
```